# Declaration inconsistency on private slots Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Yesterday I was working with a project in Qt, so I made a delayed call to a slot that I thought it was public. So I wrote :

```
QTimer::singleShot();
```

calling that slot but finally I saw that slot was private.

This could be a workaround to private slots :

```
QTimer::singleShot(0,class,SLOT(class::privateSlot()))
```

Why there is this inconsistency on declaration in Qt?

Comment: What do you mean as 'inconsistency'? You can actually call private slots via Qt signal-slot system (i.e. indirectly).

Comment: it s called *private* when actually private it is not..

Comment: yes. http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/signalsandslots.html "Since slots are normal member functions, they follow the normal C++ rules when called directly. However, as slots, they can be invoked by any component, regardless of its access level, via a signal-slot connection. This means that a signal emitted from an instance of an arbitrary class can cause a private slot to be invoked in an instance of an unrelated class." It's a documented Qt design defect.

Comment: you are right! it's something known! thank u

Answer (score 2):

A little bit widening of @hate-engine's answer

Find out and look at file with name of your source and prefix `moc_` (for example `moc_my_class.cpp`). This file was generated by moc-compiler when you added `Q_OBJECT` macro in you class declaration. This macro adds a couple of methods to your class declaration, and `moc_my_class.cpp` contains definitions of that methods.

Now look at method `MyClass::qt_metacall`. This method can be called from other place because it is public. In other hand it can call private methods of `MyClass`, because they belong to  class `MyClass`.

There's no mystery ))